# What packages are needed for Android SDK when use another emulator like Genymotion

Tags: android, sdk, package, emulation, genymotion

I have install Android Studio on my PC and for work faster I use Genymotion for emulator.

My Question is:
Should I install these packages for every API Version:

- API-x
- Platform-Tools
- Build-Tools
- System-Images
- Genymotion Android-x

or just some packages works fine and which?

Thanks.

Comment: If you install the genymotion system images, its ok. Not necessary to install platform tools or build tools as in android studio. Works for me very fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With genymotion you dont need to install any of these packages.
all you will need to do is to choose which android device image you want to use. choose device and download its image and it will work.

Comment: yes it works in eclipse too. just run your genymotion device first and then run your application, the device chooser dialog will show your genymotion device. click on it and it will work fine.